# What is a best practice for building rust in VS Code with rust (rls) extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, rust

With rustc 1.34.2 (I don't know how to get overall version but hopefully that is indicative) and VS Code 1.33.1 and rust(rls) 0.6.1, if I create a workspace with multiple projects (freshly created from `cargo new`), when I try to build:

[image]

I do not get an option to select which project to build:

[image]

This is not ideal and at this stage I'm honestly not sure what dictates which one it lets me build. Is there a way to find this out?

Not being an expert in VS Code (or rust) I've since searched around for some test.json files to attempt to build. The ones on stackoverflow seem quite dated dated but I found one from here that is at least recent: https://gist.github.com/deadalusai/9e13e36d61ec7fb72148

If I add this (either the 0.1.0 or 2.0.0) to my `test3/.vscode/tasks.json` and `test4/.vscode/tasks.json`, I can build those projects:

[image]

However, with errors in my test3 project I cannot click on the `src\lib.rs` to go to that line. It's hard to show but when I use my cursor to hover over the red highlight area, nothing comes up and I cannot navigate to that code

[image]

The odd thing is for test4 project it works as I hoped:

[image]

The difference between test3 and test4 is that test3 was created with `cargo new test3 --lib` and test4 was created with `cargo new test4 --bin`. But my hope or expectation is that this capability would be available in either type of project.

I can appreciate I should probably do some more reading about VS Code as it is also very new to me, to be honest my focus at the moment is learning rust, which I'd like to do in an IDE with rudimentary features. Just wondering if I have missed a beginner friendly guide for setting up rust VS Code, or is what I've experienced simply the state of the art at the moment?